# LLA vs ECEF--which to choose?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, latitude-longitude, position

I will be providing points in 3D to an external source via XML. One coworker suggests Lat/Long/Alt and another suggests ECEF. We can do either without much trouble.

We have an existing product that uses ECEF, and would like to bolt more things onto it. The new features are natively in Lat/Long/Alt.

Should I prefer LLA or ECEF for communicating with the external world?

As background, this is an embedded system outputing live updates of items moving in 3D space, at a rate of around 1Hz. The items tracked will be within a 300km radius around our customer's facility. Our customer is writing custom software to parse this on their end and use the data in their existing tool. We can choose any format we wish. I just wondered if there was a preferable format.

Comment: I don't think you're providing us with enough context (eg, the application domain) to answer. Why not provide _both_ options?

Comment: @martinf I updated with a bit more context. Thanks for your input.

Comment: For future Googlers, we chose to go with ECEF simply because of the existing product that uses ECEF, not for any technical reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure you understand the difference between reference frame and coordinate systems... re, Earth Center Earth Fixed - REFERENCE SYSTEM and Latitude, Longitude, Altitude is the coordinate system... the are NOT mutually exclusive. now, had you said ECEF vs ECI or LLA vs XYZ - that would make more sense! So there you have it!